# Is there a way to compare year totals depending on selected year parameter in SSRS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, report

The background is the following:

- I have a script that loads monthly aggregated data into a table
- I read data from that table with Report builder to make a report
- The report uses a multi-value 'year' parameter

So far so good, everything works like a charm

**The problem:**
Management wants to see a comparison between the year totals.
*Example : If the user selected 2018 and 2017, the report should display all data from 2018 and 2017 (so far OK) + a percentage value (growth) between the year totals*
Is there an option in the table settings to show this?
or alternatively
How do I write an expression that references the 'inbound call' total for 2018 and 2017 etc.?

My initial workaround was that I used a single value parameter, then configured 2 different dataset, 1 for the selected year and one for the selected year - 1
This made it easy to compare values

[image]

**In short:**

How do I divide year parameter 1 total with year parameter 2 total using either expressions or some inbuilt function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this in SSRS, but it probably isn't the best way to solve the problem.  I mocked up a quick example, basically I created two datasets:

- DS2016 - with totals for 2016;
- DS2017 - with totals for 2017.

I can show a list of categories, and total profit from my DS2017 dataset, adding these into a Tablix.  I can then insert a new calculated column to compare the values to 2016, where the formula looks like this:

```
=Sum(Fields!total.Value, "DS2017") * 100 / Sum(Fields!total.Value, "DS2016")
```

The trick here is to make use of the "scope" (at least that's what I think it's called) parameter, to say which dataset to use, otherwise it will default to the dataset you picked for the Tablix.

Now I can run my report and see the growth from 2016.

However, you would be much better advised to go back to your original SQL query, and change this to do the work for you.  This will be much faster than letting SSRS do all the heavy lifting.

Comment: Hi Richard,  
thanks for your input. I thought of something like this already but the comparisons should be dependent on the paramaters selected. Let's say the user selects more than 2 years. What happens? How would you go about it?

Comment: Anonymise your datasets, and have a "year" parameter for each one.  Now you can pick any two years, e.g. 2015 to 2019, etc. and it will still show the growth from one dataset to the next.  If you are saying the user can select more than two years to show results for, well now you have a totally different report, and a different problem.  What would you show now, the difference from Year A to Year B, then from Year B to Year C, finally Year A to Year C?

Comment: But personally I would ditch all of this, and write a stored procedure that runs the comparison for you, then simply add this to SSRS.

Comment: Well I thought that it should always compare years to the previous years. So if 2019-2018-2017 are seleceted 2019 is compared to 2018 and 2018 is compared to 2017
To be frank, I'm not exactly familiar with stored procedures.

Comment: the following code works. It's a bit wonky because of the parameter selection 
=Sum(IIF(Fields!cryear.Value=Parameters!year.Value(0),Fields!calls_agent_reached.value,0),"ZusammenFassung") / Sum(IIF(Fields!cryear.Value=Parameters!year.Value(1),Fields!calls_agent_reached.value,0),"ZusammenFassung")